# Matplotlib Colormap Gray generates different results on a binary array of type int32

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, python-3.8

- Goal: Avoid File Write/Read Operations
- Task: Generate RGBA image as shown in the picture below (img1 from the code)
  [image]
- Issue: Without file write and read operations, Getting Black Image as shown in the picture below  (img2 from the code)
  [image]

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from PIL import Image

# download file from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R9MEeK-7vUM59An-frFtZv2dtTw-jhs7/view?usp=sharing
bin_mask = np.load("bin_mask.npy") # 

# Method1: Does unnecessary file write/read but works
plt.imsave('img1.png', bin_mask, cmap=cm.gray)
img1 = Image.open('img1.png') 

# Method 2: No file write but img1 != img2;
# Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965417/how-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-pil-image-applying-matplotlib-colormap
img2 = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(cm.gray(bin_mask)*255)) 

# unique values of img1: [0, 255]; dtype=uint8
# unique values of img2: [0, 1, 255]; dtype=uint8

print("img1 same as img2: ", img1 == img2) # False
```

- This task seems trivial at first sight but I'm not sure why its behaving this way.
  Any suggestions would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have same results from both images when bin_mask value is 0 and different when it is 1.

```
print('Bin mask={}, img1={}, img2={}'.format(bin_mask[-1][-1] ,np.array(img1)[-1][-1] ,np.array(img2)[-1][-1] ))
# Bin mask=0, img1=[  0   0   0 255], img2=[  0   0   0 255]
print('Bin mask={}, img1={}, img2={}'.format(bin_mask[0][0] ,np.array(img1)[0][0] ,np.array(img2)[0][0] ))
# Bin mask=1, img1=[255 255 255 255], img2=[  1   1   1 255]
```

Looking further when you call cm.gray(1) gives (0.00392156862745098, 0.00392156862745098, 0.00392156862745098, 1.0) and cm.gray(255) gives (1,1,1,1). So you should be multiplying 255 with bin_mask if you looking for same result.

Following lines will result same content of Img1 and Img2.

```
img3=Image.fromarray(np.uint8(cm.gray(bin_mask*255)*255))
print(img1 == img3) #result will be false, since this is not correct way to compare data in Image
print(list(img1.getdata()) == list(img3.getdata())) # result is True
```

However the way you are doing takes too much time when it is compared with Opencv. You can do same thing using OpenCV using following way.

```
img3 = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(bin_mask.astype(np.uint8) * 255), cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA)
print('Result from Opencv=',np.all(img3 == np.array(img1))) # true
```

Refer bellow, for full code to understand and time taken by your method vs mine.

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

from PIL import Image

# download file from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R9MEeK-7vUM59An-frFtZv2dtTw-jhs7/view?usp=sharing
bin_mask = np.load("/home/jagdish/Downloads/bin_mask.npy") #

# Method1: Does unnecessary file write/read but works
plt.imsave('img1.png', bin_mask, cmap=cm.gray)
img1 = Image.open('img1.png')

# Method 2: No file write but img1 != img2;
# Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965417/how-to-convert-a-numpy-array-to-pil-image-applying-matplotlib-colormap
#Your way
img3=Image.fromarray(np.uint8(cm.gray(bin_mask*255)*255))
print('Comparing image class=',img1==img3)
print('Comparing content of Image=',list(img1.getdata()) == list(img3.getdata()))

#OpenCV way
img3 = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(bin_mask.astype(np.uint8) * 255), cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA)
print('Result from Opencv=',np.all(img3 == np.array(img1)))

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
  img3 = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(cm.gray(bin_mask,)*255))
print((time.time()-start_time)*1000)

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
  img3 = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(bin_mask.astype(np.uint8) * 255), cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA)
print((time.time()-start_time)*1000)
```

Here is time comparison for you.

Using matplotlib to process 1000 images 920 ms

using Opencv to process 1000 images 94 ms

Comment: Thanks Jagdish for the detailed response. 
It works for me.